# Can you create an Account View filtered by a junction object?

Tags: administration, relationships

I am trying to create an Account view that is filtered by values in a related junction object.  The structure looks like this: Account <= Franchise Account Association => Franchise

The Account list should be filtered to show only Accounts in a specific franchise.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't filter a list by conditions in a child object like this (time travelers: please feel free to update this answer with the date/time coordinates when salesforce.com releases this feature). You could run an Account with Franchise report to find all accounts that are in a specific franchise, however.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured.  Another idea I have is to create an APEX trigger on the child object, and have that update a field(s) on the Account.

Comment: A normal text field ought to do it, if you're daring. No reason why it couldn't work, except, of course, if you try to add a ton of franchises to an account and it gets truncated.